# How to pull down an schema-less JSON document from CosmosDB in Xamarin App

Tags: json, xamarin, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating an app in Xamarin and am having issues querying a general JSON document from my CosmosDB. I am able to query my DB with a known structure (very similar to what we see in the Xamarin ToDo Example):

```
public async static Task<List<ToDoItem>> GetToDoItems()
{
var todos = new List<ToDoItem>();

if (!await Initialize())
    return todos;

**var todoQuery = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ToDoItem>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName),
    new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
    .Where(todo => todo.Completed == false)
    .AsDocumentQuery();**

while (todoQuery.HasMoreResults)
{
    var queryResults = await todoQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<ToDoItem>();

    todos.AddRange(queryResults);
}

return todos;
}
```

The problem I see with this "code fixed scheme" approach is that if the scheme of your JSON file changes throughout development, older versions of code will overwrite the newer scheme in CosmosDB since writes to the DB are on a document level and not a property level. Instead, it would be helpful for older versions of the code to be able to pull down the latest scheme and work with the properties that it knows about without having to force the user to update.

Does anyone know how to query a schema-less JSON document out of CosmosDB? Thanks!

Comment: can you use `JObject` as the type?

Comment: Thanks so much Jason! That helps out a ton. Now I'm trying to figure out how to bring that query into my object. From what I've been reading, I need to deserialize it, but I'm not sure how to do that into an object exactly. If you have any pointers on how to pull the raw JSON data into my object, that'd be great. If not, you've helped a ton already, and I'll keep looking

Comment: Never mind @Jason, I believe I got it using:

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(JSONString);

Comment: @Matthew I help you post the answer to end this question. This can be beneficial to other community members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JObject` as the type to query a schema-less JSON document out of CosmosDB, and use following code to  pull the raw JSON data into your object:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(JSONString);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Steve!